# Option txt is overwrite drop-down arrow from select on google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, select

I have a strange problem with select on chrome. I want to add a gradient background and I managed that but my problem now is how to make the option to not overwrite my select arrow.
Maybe if I use `pointer-events:auto;` ??? 
If anyone can help I'll really appreciate.
Tkank's.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/DCjYA/361/

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? What should not overide what?

Comment: @ACarter: Pick an option from the first select and you'll see that the text is over the arrow.

Comment: check the fiddle and select a value from first select on chrome, option value is overwrite select arrow.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't notice that, sorry. Anyway you (thirtydot) have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with :

```
-webkit-padding-end: 10px;
```

this will fix your problem.